# Is it haram to read copyrighted books online?

Tags: halal-haram

Is it haram to read copyrighted books online? I want to read a book but it isn't available in my language, only in Japanese (not manga).  However, there is an English fan translation on the internet. Would it be haram to read it without the permisson of the author?

Comment: NOT DOWNLOADING, READING ONLINE ^^

Comment: ,usually, in the similar items, it is said that: you should refer to the law of that. And according to many scholars: it is haram to doing against the law. / So, it in the mentioned item, it can be remarked that: it could be haram if "without the permission of..." (AFAIK). And Allah knows best. God bless you for asking such significant and nice query.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones in that case I'd be deep in haram reading and was, as at our universities they provide free download of copy right books for the students and users.

Answer (score 0):

AoA - wow, this question looks interesting.
It is definitely not haram to read an author's published book online, of course, but maybe the author could press charges if it is an unauthorised website! So, maybe it would be better to check if the website is not illegal before reading.
Enjoy relaxing with a nice book!
-Amber

Answer (score -1):

Ha... it sounds very interesting...! Why will you need permission form the author to read his published work...!!! An author writes a book for readers to read. If he has published anything, it means that he wants that to be read.

So, if you have any book in any of the libraries such as archive or any other sources who have the *right*s of that book, it is likely that you are not doing anything wrong. For example many universities rent the database of huge journals for scientific research of their students or say SHAMELA or WAQEFAYA online Islamic Library. They are authorized. So it is permissible to use their database.